# datepicker() is working after 2 clicks instead of one when called from an onclick function on a textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datepicker

I am new to HTML so maybe this question might seem silly. 
I am making a text field where I can store the date value. I have used the datepicker() for the same. But somehow the function isn't working on a single click. It's takes two clicks for it to work. 
This is my code

```js
function clearText(defaultText, textBoxControl) {
  if (textBoxControl.value == "something") {
    textBoxControl.value = "";
    //alert("hi");
    $(function() {
      $("#watermark").datepicker();
    });

    textBoxControl.style.color = 'black';
  }
}

function createWatermark(defaultText, textBoxControl) {
  if (textBoxControl.value == "") {
    textBoxControl.value = defaultText;
    textBoxControl.style.color = 'gray';
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <input type="text" id="watermark" style="color:gray;" value="something" onclick="clearText(this.value,this)" onblur="createWatermark('something', this)">
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Call date picker outside the function.

```
$(function() {
    $("#watermark").click(function() {
        $(this).datepicker().datepicker( "show" )
    });
});
```

```js
$(function() {
    $("#watermark").click(function() {
        $(this).datepicker().datepicker( "show" )
    });
});
function clearText(defaultText, textBoxControl) {
  if (textBoxControl.value == "something") {
    textBoxControl.value = "";
    //alert("hi");
    textBoxControl.style.color = 'black';
  }
}

function createWatermark(defaultText, textBoxControl) {
  if (textBoxControl.value == "") {
    textBoxControl.value = defaultText;
    textBoxControl.style.color = 'gray';
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="watermark" style="color:gray;" value="something" onclick="clearText(this.value,this)" onblur="createWatermark('something', this)">
```

Comment: Better initialize date picker on its click function. You should initialise the date picker  not on click of the element ie ,<input>

Answer (score 0):

This is the example for datetime picker ... For more go to this [Link](http://formvalidation.io/examples/bootstrap-datepicker/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#watermark')
        .datepicker({
            format: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
            autoclose: true
        })
        .on('changeDate', function(e) {
            // Revalidate the date field
            
        });
    });
```

```css
#eventForm .form-control-feedback {
    top: 0;
    right: -15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/css/datepicker.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/css/datepicker3.min.css" />

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>

 
<form id="eventForm" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Date</label>
        <div class="col-xs-5 date">
            <div class="input-group input-append date" id="watermark">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="date" />
                <span class="input-group-addon add-on"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
         
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
<script>
     $( function() {
                $("#watermark").datepicker();
            });
  function clearText(defaultText, textBoxControl)
    {

    if(textBoxControl.value == "something")
        {
        textBoxControl.value = "";
        //alert("hi");


            textBoxControl.style.color = 'black';
        }
    }
    function createWatermark(defaultText, textBoxControl)
    {

        if(textBoxControl.value == "")
        {
            textBoxControl.value = defaultText;
            textBoxControl.style.color = 'gray';
        }
    }
    </script>
```